# Is it a good idea to nest Try/Catch for nested PDO operations?

Tags: php, pdo, try-catch

i have several database checks with PDO before i insert some values on the DB and i don't know if one try/catch will catch all errors in the nested PDO or if i need one try/catch for every PDO. This is the code i got now:

```
try {
$db = connect_db();
$q = "query foobar";
$stm = $db->prepare($q);
$stm->bindParam(1, $foobar);
$status = $stm->execute();
if ($stm->rowCount() == 0) {
    if ($def == 0) {
    $q = "query foobar";
    $stm = $db->prepare($q);
    $stm->bindParam(1, $foobar);
    $stm->bindParam(2, $foobar);
    $stm->bindParam(3, $foobar);
    $stm->bindParam(4, $foobar);
    $status = $stm->execute();
    if ($status) {
        echo "<script>alert('foobar');window.location.assign('admin.php');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('foobar');window.location.assign('admin.php');</script>";
        die();
    }
    } else {
    $q = "query foobar";
    $stm = $db->prepare($q);
    $stm->bindParam(1, $nombre);
    $status = $stm->execute();
    if ($stm->rowCount() == 0) {
        $q = "query foobar";
        $stm = $db->prepare($q);
        $stm->bindParam(1, $foobar);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $foobar);
        $stm->bindParam(3, $foobar);
        $stm->bindParam(4, $user);
        $status = $stm->execute();
        if ($status) {
        echo "<script>alert('foobar.');window.location.assign('admin.php');</script>";
        } else {
        echo "<script>alert('foobar.');window.location.assign('admin.php');</script>";
        die();
        }
    }
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('foobar.'); history.back();</script>";
    die();
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
// Proccess error
$msg = $e->getMessage();
$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$line = $e->getLine();
$code = $e->getCode();

handle_error($msg, $timestamp, $line, $code);
die("foobar");
}
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, i wasnt asking for a codereview, it was only an example. The other comment solved my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)**
>
> In addition to setting the error code, PDO will throw a PDOException and set its properties to reflect the error code and error information. This setting is also useful during debugging, as it will effectively "blow up" the script at the point of the error, very quickly pointing a finger at potential problem areas in your code (remember: transactions are automatically rolled back if the exception causes the script to terminate).
>
> Exception mode is also useful because you can structure your error handling more clearly than with traditional PHP-style warnings, and with less code/nesting than by running in silent mode and explicitly checking the return value of each database call.

So, one is enough